# How to make a Disk auto-run both in Windows and MAC OS X

Tags: cocoa, operating-system, disk, autorun

I have develop two tiny utility applications for both Windows and MAC OS X. I know how to make this disk auto-run by Window. But for MAC OS X, I've no idea how to.

Any one know about how to achieve this? Can I make **ONE** disk auto-run by **both** Windows and MAC OS X? And of cause, different OS should run different apps designed for themselves. For example, Window may run "util_Win.exe", while MAC OS X "util_MAC.app".

Comment: My understanding that this is not generally possible on a Mac because it's a vector for viruses. You can, however, have it open a folder containing your app.

Comment: @user1118321 I am using MAC OS in my virtual machine. When I connected VMTools iso disk, a window apeared: [image](http://i44.tinypic.com/11jsuph.png). This does not look like a folder...

Comment: It is a folder. You can set a background image for folders in the Finder. [See here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/28/customize-the-mac-finder-window-background/) for details.

Comment: Ah, what a trick. You can post that as an answer, including customizing background part. I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the background of a window by opening the window and choosing "Show View Options" from the "View" menu in the Finder. Once displayed, you can set the "Background" setting to "Picture" and then choose the picture you want.

[See here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/28/customize-the-mac-finder-window-background/) for an example.

Comment: As I continue looking into that, I found another interesting question. Could you please also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863053/how-to-make-icons-in-a-specific-folder-unmovable-in-mac-os-x)?