# How to make icons in a specific folder unmovable in MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, icons, finder, autorun

I installed VMTools for MAC OS X. And this is its UI:
[image]

I known that this was simply a folder. But what make me curious was that I could not drag and re-position those two icons.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: cannot see the image. Also, I don't mean to be a grammatical error pushy person, but sticked is not a word, use stuck instead

Comment: Strange. I could see the image. Actually the same image of [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839917/how-to-make-a-disk-auto-run-both-in-windows-and-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the window to "Sort By..." or "Arrange By..." some criteria. If you open the window and choose "Show View Options" from the "View" menu, you should see various options for those. Choosing "By Name", for example, will keep them sorted by name and not allow them to be moved around.

Comment: Sorry, my question was totally a silly one. That icons could not moved was because the "folder" was a read-only mounted volume. I create another iso file and tested it, and it proved that. But thank you all the same!